# Subscription Frequency and Price Change hook in Woocommerce Subscriptions

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, subscriptions

Maybe I overlooked it, but as much as I searched, I could not find which `action` to hook when a subscription changes price or frequency in Woocommerce Subscriptions.

The [documentation](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/subscriptions/develop/payment-gateway-integration/) says that to support price changes in your payment gateway you have to list `subscription_amount_changes`, but nowhere it says which function will be called when the amount actually changes..

Also in the [Action reference](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/subscriptions/develop/action-reference/) I was unable to find an action hook which is called when the subscription amount or frequency changes. If anyone has a clue which hook to use or how to implement this particular feature, please tell me.

---

### Edit

Ok thanks for the comments and answer by @Reigel, so if I understand correctly the change of a subscription in the admin menu (which I indeed refer to), has to be handled by the `save_post` action. Could you provide a small example how to hook this action and check if it is a subscription and get the `$order_id` (I guess this is the same as `post_id`?) to use in the subscription management calls?

Thank you very much already!

Comment: Are you talking about when you change the price or frequency of a subscription product in the admin area?

Comment: I could not find any documentation for what you are after. I have found that just looking through the source code of the lib have helped me many times. Looking for keywords like 'amount' or 'changes' or 'amount(' or 'changes(' using grep can help you locate the function. Please give it a go if you haven't already done so.

Comment: There is additional documentation here: https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Payment_Gateway.html which is not the clearest but might get you further. I need to ask though because it is not clear in your question can you give an example of where in the process you are trying to hook? It's hard to visualize what you are looking for. Give an example?

Comment: I also see in paypal the use of WC_Subscriptions_Manager and WC_Subscriptions_Order classes. Maybe this will be of some help. For example here: https://docs.woothemes.com/document/subscriptions/develop/functions/management-functions/, you can see WC_Subscriptions_Manager::update_users_subscriptions( $user_id, $subscription_details )

Comment: @JamesJones Yes, I want to capture a change when the subscription in the admin area changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to explain about `supports`.

`subscription_amount_changes` is just a support and will not fire anything. You can use it for conditional statements, like:

```
if ( !$chosen_gateway->supports( 'subscription_amount_changes' )) { 
     echo 'Please be considerate and do not change the price for the chosen gateway does not support it.';
}
```

now, other plugins can then check if the chosen gateway supports `subscription_amount_changes` and do their appropriate actions.

> action hook which is called when the subscription amount or frequency
>   changes

subscription is just a product type. Which means this is just a post with a `post_type` of product. The amount and frequency are just post meta. all are handled on `save_post` action. `add_action( 'save_post', __CLASS__ . '::save_subscription_meta', 11 );`. This is on the `post_type=product`. You have to check also for `save_post` on `post_type=shop_order` as it's more appropriate for checking support. Because there's already a gateway chosen.

Comment: Thank you, it gets a bit more clear, sorry that I am a bit noob at Woocommerce (it seems so ugly to use post for everything.. but ok). I updated my question to be more clear, if you could provide a very small example how to catch the post save I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 2):

This should be considered an addon to the answer by @Reigel. If you upvote this, upvote his answer too.

Here's an example of hooking the `pre_post_update` action. It occurs a little before the `save_post` action. Both actions are triggered in the `wp_insert_post()` function in `post.php`.

```
function post_save_subscription_check( $post_ID, $data )
{
    if( $data['post_type'] == 'product' ) {
        if (!empty($_POST['_subscription_price']) && get_post_meta($post_ID, '_subscription_price', true) != $_POST['_subscription_price']) {
                /* do stuff here */
        }
        if (!empty($_POST['_subscription_period']) && get_post_meta($post_ID, '_subscription_period', true) != $_POST['_subscription_period']) {
                /* do stuff here */
        }
    }
}
add_action('pre_post_update', 'post_save_subscription_check', 10, 2 );
```

- In the logic we are checking for the old value, obtained with `get_post_meta()` and the new value, held in the `$_POST` variable and comparing them.
- This code only executes when a post updates, not for a new post
- The code gets placed in your theme `functions.php` or custom plugin code.
- In live code I would recommend cleaning any `$_POST` data before using it. I haven't bothered here.

Comment: yes, this is exactly the next steps. But I still think you can use `save_post`. You just have to play with the priority. I haven't tried though..

Comment: @Reigel I used `pre_post_update` because it makes it easy to get the old value with `get_post_meta()`. `save_post` occurs just after data being written to db so it is a little harder. I agree there is probably a way to compare during `save_post` but it wouldn't be affected by hook priority.

Comment: Thank you very much @JamesJones, this is exactly what I need. I will give you the bounty and mark Reigel as the answer for his help to make it fair.

Comment: @BasvanStein. Thank you very much. I just Googled around and realised you can't split bounties.That would be ideal in a situation like this as I feel the answers really compliment each other. I don't feel too guilty taking the rep though as I need it a lot more than Reigel does!

Comment: it's fair.. no worries... ;) glad I could help.